# Ngrx finalise effect by calling common action

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I've got an application using NGRX as state management and I've got an effect which looks at the state to find an object by id, and calls the server if it fails. Both of these set the current object in the state, but I also have a loading indicator that I want the effect to handle - as if it has to call the server, there will be a delay.

I've setup my effect like this, which works:

```js
  fetchDealById$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(DealsApiActions.fetchDealById),
      concatLatestFrom(() => this.store.select(selectDeals)),
      switchMap(([action, deals]) => {
        const dealFound = deals.find(x => x.id === action.id);
        if (dealFound != undefined) return [
          DealsApiActions.setCurrentDeal({ currentDeal: dealFound }),
          DealsApiActions.setLoading({ loadingDeals: false })
        ];

        return this.dealsService.fetchDealById(action.id).pipe(
          switchMap((dealResponse: any) => [
            DealsApiActions.setCurrentDeal({ currentDeal: dealResponse.data }),
            DealsApiActions.setLoading({ loadingDeals: false })
          ])
        )
      }),
    )
  );
```

However I'm not happy with calling `setLoading` twice. I tried adding `finalize(() => DealsApiActions.setLoading({ loadingDeals: false })` (also with `this.store.dispatch()`) but it doesn't seem to fire the action.

Is there a cleaner way I can deal with common actions at the end of an effect which may or may not have N delay?

Comment: Does your pipe _complete_? `finalize` is only used when an Observable completes. If you want this to happen after every emitted value, then `tap` should work just fine (unless the pipe errors)

Comment: Where is the calling of the server in this code?

Comment: The pipe completes as it's setting the `currentDeal` in the state in the `switchMap` that's piped into the dealsService. Everything resolves and the loading state gets set to false, but not when using `finalize`/`endWith`. Perhaps a tap and some catchError handling at the end is what I should try?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two actions for this.
Instead, use `DealsApiActions.setCurrentDeal` to also set `loadingDeals` to false.

You can see an action as an event (loaded current deals), and the event can trigger multiple reducers/effects. I assume the loading indicator and the deal live in the same reducer, so you can set the deal, and also set the loading indicator in one go.